# Tomcat Error after installing in NetBeans

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, java-web-start

I got a new laptop, and installed the newest NetBeans version (12.3). I wanted to install Tomcat, too, but I always get the following silent Error in NetBeans when I'm trying to start Tomcat:

class.org.netbeans.modules.tomcat5.deploy.tomcatmanagerimpl cannot access class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.base64 because module java.xml does not export com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util to unnamed module

I tried multiple different versions of Tomcat (8, 9, 10), but I always got the same result. I don't know what to do anymore, has anyone an idea?

Comment: [1] Update your question to state the Java version that NetBeans is running on, since that is also the version that will be used to start Tomcat. You can get that information by opening the **Help > About** window. [2] Note that NetBeans 12.3 does not support JDK 16, so if that is what you are using you must configure NetBeans to use JDK 15 instead.

Comment: @skomisa, thank you very much! I changed the jdkhome of netbeans to Java 12 and now it works

Comment: It's good that it is working now. But please consider posting a detailed answer to your own question, clarifying the cause of the problem, and the versions of the NetBeans-Java-Tomcat combination that resolved the issue. That will be much more helpful to the SO community than merely having information in the comments.